# How to add a widget to the bottom of the screen in a list view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a list of widgets in a `ListView` but there is a particular widget (version of the application) I want to add to the bottom of the screen. I tried to wrap it in a `Container` but it didn't change the result much. Here is my [image: screenshot] and my code below:

```
  const SelectDatabase({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SelectDatabase> createState() => _SelectDatabaseState();
}

class _SelectDatabaseState extends State<SelectDatabase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  reverse: true,
                  children: [
                    addVSpace(20),
                    Container(
                      height: 120,
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/logo.svg'),
                    ),
                    addVSpace(100),
                    ExpansionTile(
                      iconColor: kPrimaryColor,
                      collapsedIconColor: kPrimaryColor,
                      title: Text(
                        'Select Database',
                        style: kMainStyling,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        //Some Code Here

                      ],
                      onExpansionChanged: (isExpanded){
                        print ('Database $isExpanded is selected' );
                      },
                    ),
                    addVSpace(20),
                    TextFieldWidget(
                      labelText: 'Username',
                      hintText: 'Username',
                    ),
                    addVSpace(20),
                    PasswordTextField(
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      labelText: 'Password',
                    ),
                    addVSpace(20),
                    BigButton(label: 'Sign In', ontap: (){}),
                  ].reversed.toList(),
                ),
              ),
              Center(child: Text('Version 1.0.0', style: kMainStyling,),),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using a ListView in this case ? Better use Column and Row

Do something like this :

```
SafeArea
    Column
        Row
            Expanded
                Your login form
        Row
            SizedBox
                Your version information
```

By setting the heigth of your size box, the Expanded will expand all free space

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `Column` give it's property to `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.